# Get page content by slug or title wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a blog and I have difficulty with pages in wordpress, in my case I would like to insert content (raw content) from two pages randomly in modal system while people browse the blog.

**Example:**
Current Page> Modal Box> Page01 content or Page02 Content

I know it's possible by the page id. but I would like to make it more dynamic by getting the contents of the pages by slugs or by title.

here's the code

```
<?php

  $term = get_taxonomy( $slug );

  $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'page', 
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'orderby' => 'RAND',
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => $term,
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array('page-01', 'page-02'),
    ) )
  );

  $rand = new WP_Query($args);

  if ($rand->have_posts()) {
    while ($rand->have_posts()) {
      $rand->the_post();
      the_content();
    }
  }
?>
```

I know that removing taxonomy from query gets the contents of publish pages but, in my case, I need to get content from two specific pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `post_name__in` to filter by multiple slugs, eg:

```
  $args = array( 
    'post_name__in' => array('page-slug-1', 'page-slug-2'),
    'post_type' => 'page', 
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'orderby' => 'RAND',
  );
```

You can find more details on the [WP_Query documentation page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

Comment: Good sir, thank you for your answer, it made my day, thank you for you reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get page content.

Use [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and the parameter name which is as slug:

```
$page = get_posts([ 'name' => 'page-slug','post_type' => 'page' ]);

if ( $page )
{
    echo $page[0]->post_content;
}
```

The post_type in get_posts() defaults to 'post'. If you want to get pages, use like this.

```
$page = get_posts([
    'name'      => 'your-slug',
    'post_type' => 'page'
]);
var_dump($page); //to check the outputs
```